# how to implement Grad-CAM on your own network?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I want to implement Grad-CAM on my own network, should I save my model and load it, then treat my saved model like VGG-16, then do similar operations?

I tried to search on the internet, and I found that all methods are based on famous models, not their owns.

So I wonder, maybe I just need to treat my own model as VGG-16, then do similar things.

Comment: Too busy to follow up later, but I just did this. Before running forward or backward, access your layer on which you want to apply GradCam, say using c = list(self.model.children())[-3][2].conv3 for resnet. The apply forward and backward hook on c which stores `            def hook_feature(module, input, output):
                self.features = output.clone().detach()` and `            def hook_gradient(module, grad_in, grad_out):
                self.gradients = grad_out[0].clone().detach()`

Comment: Will add this as a proper answer later. See this code :- https://github.com/utkuozbulak/pytorch-cnn-visualizations/blob/master/src/gradcam.py#L30 . This one works with VGG kind of networks only where there is one sequential block. Unlike resnet which has nested blocks of layers. Edit this code to add your custom layer selection and use forward and backward hook instead of `register_hook` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have one solution in pytorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils import data
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# use the ImageNet transformation
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)), 
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

# define a 1 image dataset
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='./data/Elephant/', transform=transform)

# define the dataloader to load that single image
dataloader = data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)

vgg19 = Mymodel() ## create an object of your model
vgg19.load_state_dict(torch.load("your_vgg19_weights"))
class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        
        # get the pretrained VGG19 network
        self.vgg = vgg19
        
        # disect the network to access its last convolutional layer
        self.features_conv = self.vgg.features[:36]  # 36th layer was my last conv layer
        
        # get the max pool of the features stem
        self.max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
        
        # get the classifier of the vgg19
        self.classifier = self.vgg.classifier
        
        # placeholder for the gradients
        self.gradients = None
    
    # hook for the gradients of the activations
    def activations_hook(self, grad):
        self.gradients = grad
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features_conv(x)
        
        # register the hook
        h = x.register_hook(self.activations_hook)
        
        # apply the remaining pooling
        x = self.max_pool(x)
        x = x.view((1, -1))
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
    
    # method for the gradient extraction
    def get_activations_gradient(self):
        return self.gradients
    
    # method for the activation exctraction
    def get_activations(self, x):
        return self.features_conv(x)

vgg = VGG()

# set the evaluation mode
vgg.eval()

# get the image from the dataloader
img, _ = next(iter(dataloader))

# get the most likely prediction of the model
pred_class = vgg(img).argmax(dim=1).numpy()[0]
pred = vgg(img)

pred[:, pred_class].backward()

# pull the gradients out of the model
gradients = vgg.get_activations_gradient()

# pool the gradients across the channels
pooled_gradients = torch.mean(gradients, dim=[0, 2, 3])

# get the activations of the last convolutional layer
activations = vgg.get_activations(img).detach()

# weight the channels by corresponding gradients
for i in range(512):
    activations[:, i, :, :] *= pooled_gradients[i]
    
# average the channels of the activations
heatmap = torch.mean(activations, dim=1).squeeze()

# relu on top of the heatmap
# expression (2) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02391.pdf
heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0)

# normalize the heatmap
heatmap /= torch.max(heatmap)
heatmap = heatmap.numpy()

import cv2
img = cv2.imread('./data/Elephant/data/05fig34.jpg')
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
superimposed_img = heatmap * 0.4 + img
cv2.imwrite('./map.jpg', superimposed_img)  ###saves gradcam visualization image
```